# Having a strange issue using right join in query

Tags: mysql, right-join

I have this MySQL query that is supposed to give me the amount in and out of all bank accounts in the database for the last 30 days. It even fills gaps with the use of a join statement with a calendar table.

However I ran into issues limiting the dataset only to include the statements belonging to a specific account, defined by a `account_id` field.

Here is the original query that fetches all entries in database for a specific account:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(transactions.account_id) AS numTransactions,
    calendar.datefield AS date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactions.amount < 0 THEN transactions.amount ELSE 0 END) as negativeAmount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactions.amount > 0 THEN transactions.amount ELSE 0 END) as positiveAmount
FROM
    transactions
RIGHT JOIN
    calendar
ON
    DATE(transactions.accounting_date) = calendar.datefield
WHERE
    calendar.datefield BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
AND
    transactions.account_id = 1
GROUP BY
    date
ORDER BY
    date DESC;
```

This will return only the days with values for `transactions.amount` ignoring the `RIGHT JOIN calendar` clause.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it fairly quickly.

My `WHERE` clause is on the left table, and not the right (?).

This worked:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(transactions.account_id) AS numTransactions,
    calendar.datefield AS date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactions.amount < 0 THEN transactions.amount ELSE 0 END) as negativeAmount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transactions.amount > 0 THEN transactions.amount ELSE 0 END) as positiveAmount
FROM
    transactions
RIGHT JOIN
    calendar
ON
    DATE(transactions.accounting_date) = calendar.datefield
AND
    transactions.account_id = 1
WHERE
    calendar.datefield BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY
    date
ORDER BY
    date DESC;
```

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN

Comment: @Strawberry No? What do they use?

Comment: They use LEFT JOIN - it's why a search on this forum for  `"LEFT JOIN" [mysql]` throws up 15000 results vs 1200 for its counterpart. Also note that `FROM
    transactions
RIGHT JOIN
    calendar` is functionally identical to `FROM
    calendar
LEFT JOIN
    transactions`

Comment: So basically just turning it around then, that could be better though.